# Creating own string format expressions, for custom user generated output

Tags: c#

Not sure how I should word the title of this question. Searching for it is even worse. But here we go:

In my C#, if I have a DateTime and I do `.ToString()`, I can give it a custom expression, that will internally get converted to my desired output. There's a table such as this:

| Expression | Output |
| --- | --- |
| yyyy | Year (2021) |
| MM | Month (06) |
| dd | Day of month (16) |

and so on. So `date.ToString("yyyy")` returns `"2021"` for example.

I want my users to input a string, that will result in a path to a directory. I have a class with a bunch of properties to pick from. I was originally thinking about creating a massive if-statement hell and just do a bunch of `string.Replace()`, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea or not. Basically I want something like this:

```
public string GetPath(string expression, Model model)
{
    var path = expression;

    if(expression.Contains("NAME"))
    {
        path = path.Replace("NAME", model.Name);
    }

    if (expression.Contains("yyyy"))
    {
        path = path.Replace("yyyy", model.Date.ToString("yyyy"));
    }

    if (expression.Contains("ID"))
    {
        path = path.Replace("ID", model.Id);
    }

    .......

    return path;
}
```

and then give them a list of possible values that can be replaced. This can, however, introduce a lot of problems. What if the user wants the path to include "NAME" (as a string and not the class' property value)?

I want the user to be able to input something like `/yyyy/MM/dd/NAME/ID/` which in return will give me `/2021/06/16/John/12345/`, and then my program would create the folder structure:

```
2021/
├─ 06/
│  ├─ 16/
│  │  ├─ John/
│  │  │  ├─ 12345
```

Is there a term for something like this? I don't even know where to begin, except from my long if-statement hell.

Comment: I think the phrase you're looking for is _tokens_, and a popular syntax to use is `{NAME}`. That way you can distinguish between literals and tokens to substitute.

Comment: Have you looked at how the `DateTime` struct implements [`ToString(String format)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/5088b43558351160.html)?  (it uses a private [`DateTimeFormat`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/8f380a3ae5304dd7.html) class)

Comment: @gunr2171 So something like my if-statement hell proposal would actually be fine? If I just go with curly brackets around each token, I guess I should be fine

Comment: @RufusL I'm afraid that's a bit out of my league, to be honest. I skimmed through a lot of it, but couldn't really wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your users are smart enough, you can just give them instructions for a format string:

```
Path format string: [                    ]
{0} is replaced with your name, {1} is replaced with date, and takes an optional format after a colon
Example:
  {0}\{1:yyyy}\{1:MM} - John\2021\06
```

And whatever they enter, do a:

```
var path = string.Format(USER_INPUT, model.Name, model.Date)
```

---

If you want to help them out a bit:

```
Path format string: [                    ]
{name} is replaced with your name, {date} is replaced with date, and takes an optional format after a colon. Fields can be specified multiple times.
Example:
  {name}\{date:yyyy}\{date:MM} - John\2021\06
```

And perform the replacements before you format:

```
var path = string.Format(USER_INPUT.Replace("{name", "{0").Replace("{date","{1"), model.Name, model.Date)
```

---

The same technique can be extended if you want to simplify further:

```
Path format string: [                    ]
{name} is replaced with your name, 
{yyyy} is replaced with the 4 digit year
{MM} is replaced with...

Example:
  {name}\{yyyy}\{MM} - John\2021\06
```

And perform more replacements before you format:

```
var path = string.Format(USER_INPUT.Replace("{name", "{0").Replace("{yyyy","{1:yyyy").Replace("{MM","{1:MM"), model.Name, model.Date)
```

Comment: Using `string.Format()` is actually a good idea, as long as I can make a nice "catalogue" in the code, so it's easy to read for me as well (if I want to add more values in the future). Curious: Why did you only replace up until the last curly bracket? Preference?

Comment: Replacing only `{date` with `{1` allows one replacement to cater for `{date:yyyy}`, `{date:MM}` and `{date}`. If you close it off and replace `{date}` with `{1}` it kills the formatting.. Arguably you could do it in the third option

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So we use `string.Format()` to also format the DateTime, instead of doing a hacky `DateTime.ToString()` for every instance. Nice. I like that idea!

Comment: There are also options for alignments and number formatting (base) wiith string format (alignments possibly less useful in paths)

Comment: Yep, definitely. Only issue would be, if I created a custom key that starts with `{MM` for example, but I should just stay away from those